# MKS : Not able to drop member from sandbox

Tags: build, mks, mks-integrity

I created a regular sandbox in mks and until now I was able to add, drop and do all related operation in mks.  Suddenly I have started facing some problem in mks while performing operation in regular sandbox and receive the following error:

```
MKS125169: The specified operation cannot be performed from a build project or build sandbox.
```

Note: I originally created the sandbox as a regular sandbox but suddenly it had turned into build sandbox.

Can anyone explain me the reason?

How to change the sandbox back to a regular sandbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are experiencing this error is that at some point, you have re-targeted the sandbox to make it a build sandbox.

To change the sandbox to a non-build sandbox:

1. Select the sandbox
2. From the menu, select **Sandbox -> Retarget...** (If you didn't do this, you might have to customize your ViewSet to do see this option)
3. In the **Retarget Sandbox**, choose **Normal (mainline)** or **Variant** (with the correct variant selected), and hit **OK**
4. If you had a view of the sandbox open, you will have to re-open it